# CMD - How to deal with spaces in path

Tags: windows, cmd

Im trying to rewrite multiple files in folder using CMD in windows 7. Im using this code:

```
Replace C:\test\cisty_test_kabel  ploche.xlsm  C:\Káble /s
```

If i have a space somewhere in the path, the code is not working. Any idea how to fix it?

Thanks

Comment: PUt double quotes around the path: `"c:\Program Files"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any argument that contains spaces (not only paths) should be surrounded by double quotes.

This is true for all operating systems.

in your case:

```
Replace "C:\test\cisty test kabel"  ploche.xlsm  C:\Káble /s "some other string"
```