# Getting error while executing copy command in command prompt

Tags: batch-file, cmd

While executing the below command in Command Prompt,

`copy C:\Users\ADMIN\Downloads\*.*  C:\Users\ADMIN\Downloads\SELF STUDY\DOCS\Completed`

I am facing the below error

`Syntax of the command is incorrect`

Can you please let me know where I am going wrong..??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CMD - How to deal with spaces in path](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27034998/cmd-how-to-deal-with-spaces-in-path)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like:

```
copy "C:\Users\ADMIN\Downloads\*.*"  "C:\Users\ADMIN\Downloads\SELF STUDY\DOCS\Completed"
```

the error is printed because the space in the target folder and copy commands takes it as two arguments.Quotes should fix this.

Comment: Yes.....Exactly. It worked. I forgot that SELF STUDY in there has spaces. Thanks for your quick reply.

Answer (score 2):

```
copy "C:\Users\ADMIN\Downloads\*.*"  "C:\Users\ADMIN\Downloads\SELF STUDY\DOCS\Completed"
```

You should add double quotes around the filenames.

Comment: Yes.....Exactly. It worked. I forgot that SELF STUDY in there has spaces. Thanks for your quick reply.